# Create .NET Distributable with Clojure-clr

Tags: .net, clojure

I am interested in creating a .NET distributable with Clojure-clr, similar to using `lein uberjar` on the jvm.  I have downloaded the Clojure-clr binary files https://github.com/clojure/clojure-clr/downloads and can run the repl, however if I run Clojure.Compile.exe the program hangs.  Presumably Clojure.Compile.exe wants additional arguments however I cannot find any documentation for how to use it.  Does anybody have any experience or is this a dead project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to compile using https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-clr and carefully following quick start in 3 steps.  I was using Windows 8.1 with the default .NET 4.5.  To use the binary Clojure.Compile.exe directly you would have to browse the source code as the exectuable does not display usage instructions when called without arguments.